# Angularjs launching window.open from ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that has a number of dependent parameters fields.  That is, changing one parameters field value may cause a server request to repopulate the other parameter fields.  After the user sets all of the fields they will press a button and launch in a popup window a new form running the report they specified.

To get the URL for this window I need to make one final call to the server which will return the formatted URL (using GET).  So the resultant flow on button click is:

- Gather values from fields
- Call web service to construct URL.  (I will use a promise)
- Launch open.window with new URL

The first 2 steps are straight-forward, but I am unsure on how to handle the window.open from the controller.  Any thoughts or ideas?

P.S.
I thought about using a directive to overwrite the link URL as values changes, but having to go back to server to construct the URL after each parameter changed seems like way too much processing.

Comment: Ignore this.   I found $window and all is well with $window.open()  Somedays ......

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for wasting people's time.  The answer is $window.open() from the controller.

Comment: Actually you could have used `window.open()` as well.I don't know what puzzled you. (Ofcourse using `$window` is preferrable, e.g. from a testability point of view)

Comment: It just plain doesnt work in ng-click which sucks, but in controller is working perfect